# Why do I need to define a reference to a pointer in C with *?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, reference, pass-by-reference

Why is this valid:

```
int a = 5;
int *aPtr = &a;
printf("%i", *aPtr);
```

But this isn't:

```
int a = 5;
int aPtr = &a;
printf("%i", *aPtr);
```

I'm not looking for the error it throws. I'm trying to understand why this wouldn't work conceptually.

Comment: What a strange question. If the rules of the language demand from you to use an asterisk for pointer declaration, then **you need an asterisks** for pointer declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int aPtr = &a;` declares an object named `aPtr` with the type `int`, so it's not a pointer.

To make things worse, `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)` on several common platforms (e.g. all x64 versions of Windows since Windows XP), so you'd lose some of the information that the pointer contains, possibly rendering the value stored useless.

Assuming it works, however, `aPtr` is still an object of type `int`, so you can't use pointer indirection to get the value stored at the address in `aPtr`, meaning the expression `*aPtr` will not compile.  There's nothing stopping you from casting `aPtr` to the proper pointer type:

```
int a = 5;
int aPtr = &a;
printf("%i", *(int *)aPtr);
```

Again, this is assuming that `aPtr` stores the complete address of `a`.  Anyway, this is just C's type safety at play, and that's a good thing (see `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)` paragraph above).

If by "conceptually" you mean "assuming the address is properly stored in `aPtr`", there's nothing wrong with your code other than the fact that it's not valid C, as the cast example above showed.  If the address was 0x80, you could even store it in a tiny little `unsigned char` object if you wanted.  It's stored at that address in memory, regardless of what C prevents you from doing with it by refusing to compile the syntactically invalid code.  Of course, it's far easier to just use the proper variable type, instead of fighting the compiler and casting things.

Then again, you might be asking, "If `&a` is stored in `aPtr`, why can't the compiler recognize that and simply understand `*aPtr` means the same thing as `*&a`?"  If that's the question, then the answer is simple: once you store `&a` in an object of some type `T`, the compiler understands that object is used to store values of type `T` and that's all.  It doesn't know that it contains a memory address, regardless of whether you stored one in that object or not; it just knows there's a value of type `T` stored inside.  Again, this is just C's type system working as intended.

Comment: JFYI: if you want to convert memory pointer into integer, there's specialized type in [C for that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer): `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. These are guaranteed to be large enough to store memory pointer without truncating it's value.

Comment: Yes, that is true. It's important to understand, however, that [they're not required to be declared](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4) ("These types are optional."), just like the [exact-width integer types such as `int64_t` and `uint8_t`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1). That said, if you're limiting your code to a specific set of platforms that you know provides them, they're great tools to have.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't work because :

```
sizeof(int)  == 4; // Bytes (usually)
sizeof(int*) == 8; // Bytes (assuming x86_64)
```

Therefore, when assigning `int aPtr = &a;`, the most significant 4 bytes would be lost.

This will work just find (though not advised) :

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
        int a = 5;
        uint64_t aPtr = (uint64_t)&a;
        printf("%i", *(int*)aPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**case 1 :-**

```
int a = 5;
int *aPtr = &a; /*this is valid bcz aptr is pointer and it need address and `&a` is valid address*/
printf("%i", *aPtr);/* here you can do *aptr, bcz aptr is pointer and
                     we can dereference pointer variable */
```

**Case 2 :-** when you do `int aptr = &a;` read the compiler warning by compiling with `-Wall`, it says everything.

```
int a = 5;
int aPtr = &a;/* aptr is normal variable, you are assigning address to it ,but you can't dereference it like *aptr bcz aptr is not pointer */
```

Since `aptr` is normal variable, when you do `*aptr` it throws the error as dereference operator `*` is applicable on pointer variable, not on normal variable.

```
printf("%i", *aPtr); /* invalid */
```

Comment: I think you mean **r-value** instead of **constant**.

Answer (score 0):

The first is invalid because & is a unary operator that requires an lvalue (variable), and cannot be applied to an rvalue (constant).

That prevents the second from being valid for the same reason. But suppose you replaced `5` with the variable you created:

```
int a = 5;
int aPtr = &a;
printf("%i", *aPtr);
```

Then C's static type checking will see that `aPtr` is of type `int`, `a` is of type `int` (thus `&a` is of type `int*`), and then cast (with a warning) `&a` from `int*` to `int`, then store that address *as an* `int` into `aPtr`. You will then run into an error when `*` dereferences `aPtr`, since `aPtr` is of type `int`. Since you've casted from `int*` to `int`, `aPtr` is now an `int`, not an `int*`.

If you fixed this as follows:

```
int a = 5;
int aPtr = &a;
printf("%i", aPtr);
```

then it would compile, printing the address of `a` (a variable allocated on the stack), although it would still give a warning for the cast from `int*` to `int`.

edit: beaten to the punch.